# Trying to place bullets of the nivo slider on the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, nivo-slider

I'm working on a Nivo Slider for my website, and I'm facing a problem with the bullets of the slider. I want them on the images of the slider. Now they are on my menu.
Like this:
[image]

This is the nivo-slider.css file:

```
/*
 * jQuery Nivo Slider v3.2
 * http://nivo.dev7studios.com
 *
 * Copyright 2012, Dev7studios
 * Free to use and abuse under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

/* The Nivo Slider styles */
.nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    max-width: none;
}
.nivo-main-image {
    display: block !important;
    position: relative !important; 
    width: 100% !important;
}

/* If an image is wrapped in a link */
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    z-index:6;
    display:none;
    background:white; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=0); 
    opacity:0;
}
/* The slices and boxes in the Slider */
.nivo-slice {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
}
.nivo-box {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.nivo-box img { display:block; }

/* Caption styles */
.nivo-caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    z-index:8;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=8);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.nivo-caption p {
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
}
.nivo-caption a {
    display:inline !important;
}
.nivo-html-caption {
    display:none;
}
/* Direction nav styles (e.g. Next & Prev) */
.nivo-directionNav a {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    z-index:9;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-prevNav {
    left:0px;
}
.nivo-nextNav {
    right:0px;
}
/* Control nav styles (e.g. 1,2,3...) */
.nivo-controlNav {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 15px 0;
}

.nivo-controlNav a {
    position: relative;
    z-index:1000;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

And this is default.css

```
/*
Skin Name: Nivo Slider Default Theme
Skin URI: http://nivo.dev7studios.com
Description: The default skin for the Nivo Slider.
Version: 1.3
Author: Gilbert Pellegrom
Author URI: http://dev7studios.com
Supports Thumbs: true
*/

.theme-default .nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
    background:#fff url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    /*-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #4a4a4a;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #4a4a4a;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #4a4a4a;*/
}
.theme-default .nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
}
.theme-default .nivoSlider a {
    border:0;
    display:block;
}

.theme-default .nivo-controlNav {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.theme-default .nivo-controlNav a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    background:url(images/bullets.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
    margin: 0;
}
.theme-default .nivo-controlNav a.active {
    background-position:0 -22px;
}

.theme-default .nivo-directionNav a {
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:url(images/arrows.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.theme-default:hover .nivo-directionNav a { opacity: 1; }
.theme-default a.nivo-nextNav {
    background-position:-30px 0;
    right:15px;
}
.theme-default a.nivo-prevNav {
    left:15px;
}

.theme-default .nivo-caption {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.theme-default .nivo-caption a {
    color:#fff;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #fff;
}
.theme-default .nivo-caption a:hover {
    color:#fff;
}

.theme-default .nivo-controlNav.nivo-thumbs-enabled {
    width: 100%;
}
.theme-default .nivo-controlNav.nivo-thumbs-enabled a {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.theme-default .nivo-controlNav.nivo-thumbs-enabled img {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    height: auto;
}
```

I'd really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you provide a fiddle you will get answers faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to actually give you a working example from the code you provided above, but I went to Nivo Slider's page and played with one of their demos in the console. What you can do is change this:

```
/* Control nav styles (e.g. 1,2,3...) */
.nivo-controlNav {
   text-align:center;
   padding: 15px 0;
}
```

to

```
/* Control nav styles (e.g. 1,2,3...) */
.nivo-controlNav {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 800px; /*CHANGE THIS VALUE TO FIT YOUR NEEDS*/
    left: 200px; /*CHANGE THIS VALUE TO FIT YOUR NEEDS*/
    z-index: 5; /*MAKE THIS HIGHER IF THE BUTTONS ARE NOT ON TOP OF THE IMAGE IN YOUR            
                EXAMPLE, THIS WAS ENOUGH ON NIVO'S SITE*/
}
```